Wi-fi Multiband Router doesn't provide proper IP Adress to Linux
Recently my network provider changed my router to a "newer" one.
But I'm having issues to connect to the router from linux devices.
The new router has a technology that my network isn't divided into two any more like:
[SSID] and [SSID]-5G
However, it's been said to me that it would detect "automatically" the optimal network to be connected to.
But my devices do connect to the network but get no IP Address. And from terminal when I ping some site this is what I get:
$ ping duck.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

After some research with the little information provided on the router, I suppose is due to Wi-Fi Agile Multiband
What should I do to have internet connection ?
Thanks in advance

call your ISP tech support

From my experience, Wi-Fi roaming (and as such, multiband) on Linux is essentially broken. But maybe you can instruct your Wi-Fi management software (NetworkManager or whatever) to connect to a specific BSSID (not a typo).

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/833905/how-can-i-connect-to-a-specific-bssid, for an example.
